# Postgres deadlocks during concurrent upserts from temporary tables

Tags: python, postgresql

I have process that is controlled by Airflow that generates a number of tasks performing concurrent inserts to a Postgres database.

Each task takes a pandas dataframe, inserts the rows to a temporary table, then upserts from the temporary table to the target table. This is leading to deadlocks, but I am having a tough time understanding how to mitigate this issue. I have pulled out the salient components here, though please let me know if I have failed to include enough information.

I am in python 3.8.2, postgres 11.7, airflow 1.10.10, and using psycopg2 as an odbc connection.

```
# create temp table like target table
temp_table_sql = 'CREATE TEMP TABLE mur_global_raw_tmp_61400102 (Like mur_global_raw INCLUDING IDENTITY);'
cur.execute(temp_table_sql)

# serialize dataframe and copy to temp table
pd_df_serial = StringIO()
pd_df.to_csv(pd_df_serial, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
pd_df_serial.seek(0)

cur.copy_from(pd_df_serial, temp_table_name, null="", columns=pd_df.columns.to_list())
conn.commit()

# upsert from temp table to target table
pd_df_insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO mur_global_raw(lat,lon,time,analysed_sst)
    (SELECT lat,lon,time,analysed_sst FROM mur_global_raw_tmp_61400102
    as tmp_vals ORDER BY lat,lon,time,analysed_sst)
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;'

cur.execute(pd_df_insert_sql)
conn.commit()
```

Here is the schema of the temporary table.

```
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default              | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 ind          | bigint                   |           | not null | generated by default as identity | plain   |              |
 lat          | double precision         |           |          |                                  | plain   |              |
 lon          | double precision         |           |          |                                  | plain   |              |
 time         | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                  | plain   |              |
 analysed_sst | double precision         |           |          |                                  | plain   |              |
```

And here is the schema of the target table.

```
    Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |             Default              | Storage | Stats target | Description
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 ind          | bigint                   |           | not null | generated by default as identity | plain   |              |
 lat          | double precision         |           |          |                                  | plain   |              |
 lon          | double precision         |           |          |                                  | plain   |              |
 time         | timestamp with time zone |           |          |                                  | plain   |              |
 analysed_sst | double precision         |           |          |                                  | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "mur_global_raw_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (ind)
```

And finally, here is a sample from the server log:

```
2020-06-22 23:03:36 UTC::@:[3570]:LOG: checkpoint starting: xlog
2020-06-22 23:03:42 UTC:xxxxx(38068):postgres@public_data_raw:[13975]:WARNING: there is no transaction in progress
2020-06-22 23:03:43 UTC:xxxxx(38090):postgres@public_data_raw:[13993]:ERROR: deadlock detected
2020-06-22 23:03:43 UTC:xxxxx(38090):postgres@public_data_raw:[13993]:DETAIL: Process 13993 waits for ShareLock on transaction 42977; blocked by process 14014.
Process 14014 waits for ShareLock on transaction 42981; blocked by process 14021.
Process 14021 waits for ShareLock on transaction 42980; blocked by process 13993.
Process 13993: INSERT INTO mur_global_raw(lat,lon,time,analysed_sst) (SELECT lat,lon,time,analysed_sst FROM mur_global_raw_tmp_75410038 as tmp_vals ORDER BY lat,lon,time,analysed_sst) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
Process 14014: INSERT INTO mur_global_raw(lat,lon,time,analysed_sst) (SELECT lat,lon,time,analysed_sst FROM mur_global_raw_tmp_41473761 as tmp_vals ORDER BY lat,lon,time,analysed_sst) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
Process 14021: INSERT INTO mur_global_raw(lat,lon,time,analysed_sst) (SELECT lat,lon,time,analysed_sst FROM mur_global_raw_tmp_28913605 as tmp_vals ORDER BY lat,lon,time,analysed_sst) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
2020-06-22 23:03:43 UTC:xxxxx(38090):postgres@public_data_raw:[13993]:HINT: See server log for query details.
2020-06-22 23:03:43 UTC:xxxxx(38090):postgres@public_data_raw:[13993]:CONTEXT: while inserting index tuple (1969403,34) in relation "mur_global_raw"
2020-06-22 23:03:43 UTC:xxxxx(38090):postgres@public_data_raw:[13993]:STATEMENT: INSERT INTO mur_global_raw(lat,lon,time,analysed_sst) (SELECT lat,lon,time,analysed_sst FROM mur_global_raw_tmp_75410038 as tmp_vals ORDER BY lat,lon,time,analysed_sst) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

These deadlocks are happening persistently and regularly, so hopefully there is a component of the design that I can address to avoid them. My understanding of the locks going on is clearly not good enough to address the problem at this stage.

If anyone can help me understand the locks and transactions that are leading to this three-way deadlock, I would most appreciate it. Of course, if you have an idea for how to avoid it, I welcome that as well.

My humble thanks to the SO community.

Comment: Mysterious, since you use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Do you have any unique indexes/constraints other than the primary key on the generated identity column?  If not, why the ON CONFLICT?

Comment: I don't have unique constraints yet- I need to backfill historical data in large quantities and will build indices afterwards. The above was put together with future upserts in mind, when unique constraints would be present. Do you see a way that the ON CONFLICT and/or upsert logic in general might affect the deadlock issue @jjanes?

Comment: I don't know what could be causing the deadlock.  Since you don't yet have a unique index, I would drop the ON CONFLICT for now and see if that fixes it.  Whichever way it goes, it provides a valuable piece of info for tracking down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

THe best workaround I've got is to add an exlusive lock before starting the upsert, like so:

```
LOCK TABLE mur_global_raw IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

Any comments welcome.

Comment: This will prevent concurrent autovacuum workers from running, so if you do that all the time, you are headed for trouble.

Comment: Good point, and thanks for the comments. Can you help me understand the length and frequency required with no locking to allow for autovaccum processes to run without issue?

Comment: This is a pretty solid rundown on autovaccum it looks like: https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/08/10/tuning-autovacuum-in-postgresql-and-autovacuum-internals/ 

There is not really a case for updates/deletes on this table, at least during the primary backfill of historical data. Additionally, there are periods between inserts of at least 10 minutes, usually more, when there are no locks on the table, even if the backfill process is running continuously.

Comment: Turn `log_autovacuum_min_duration` to 0 and see in the log how long it takes for the table. Taking a step back: Since your solution effectively disables concurrency, what is the benefits of importing in several threads?

Comment: @ConnorDibble we're you ever able to find a concurrent solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot figure out a better way, catch the deadlock errors and repeat the transaction. If the deadlocks happen a lot, that is annoying and will harm performance, but it is better than a table lock, because it won't prevent autovacuum from doing its important work.

Perhaps you can reduce the size or duration of the batches to make a deadlock less likely.

Comment: I did play with batch sizes to no avail, but I'll revisit this. Perhaps my idea of reduced batch size was not enough. I'll see what it would take to get each individual insert to be very short. Currently, each batch can take 3 to 5 minutes.

Comment: Several minutes is extremely long. Tuning there might be your best way forward. Use prepared statements or - even better - `COPY`.